# What did Tony Stark say to the press?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, spider-man-homecoming

At the end of *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, after Peter Parker

> rejects Tony Stark's offer to join the Avengers,

Peter leaves Tony and Pepper without an announcement for the assembled press.

In a seemingly spur of the moment decision, Tony asks Happy if he still has

> Pepper's engagement ring that he had been holding on to since 2008.

After some discussion, Tony and Pepper then walk out on stage to a crowd of reporters to make their important announcement.

Was the scene left intentionally vague, or

> Did Tony Stark propose to Pepper Potts?

Comment: Steven, I have added some spoiler tags and done a bit of rewording to fit them in better.  I feel that this does not change the question significantly, but if you disagree feel free to revert.

Comment: @Jeff Thank you for the edits. I think this is a significantly better format for hiding spoilers.

Comment: We don't see, in the end. Pepper says "I'm sure we can come up with something better", implying she'd rather Tony didn't propose, but Happy throws Tony the ring anyway, just in case they _can't_ think of anything else. All in all, I think it's quite likely we'll find out whether or not he did in Infinity War, so I'm wondering whether this qualifies for the "Future Works" policy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Signs point to Tony having used the event to propose.

[Recent set photos show Pepper wearing an engagement ring on the set of Avengers 4](http://pagesix.com/2017/08/23/gwyneth-rocks-engagement-ring-on-avengers-set/).

[image: He went to Jared]

Technically, this doesn't mean that they used the event to propose - it could have happened later, but given the scene in at the end of *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, and this evidence, we can reasonably assume that it happened there.

Comment: The final cut of *Infinity War* confirmed that they are engaged, but not when the proposal occurred.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think it is definitely meant to show that

> Tony Stark did propose, but in the most Tony Stark-ish way possible.

In fact, I don't think there was any ambiguity in the scene. I'll admit that it was rather sudden, considering that the last we heard about Pepper and Tony's relationship was that they were taking some time apart. I can't say that I have any evidence from the comics to back up my assertion either. In fact, in the comics, even though Pepper had feelings for Tony at one time, she eventually ended up marrying Happy, Tony's chauffeur.
However, I think others will agree with me when I say that it is fairly obvious from Pepper and Happy's reaction in the movie that Tony proposed to Pepper. Given the context, there is no other announcement to make to the reporters, and he did give her a ring after all. You have to keep in mind that Tony Stark has one of the biggest egos in the MCU, and I highly doubt that he would propose in the traditional fashion of getting down on one knee. Every action Tony makes is deliberate and taken with command. He's used to giving orders, and I think it is unlikely that he would ever *ask* Pepper to marry him. Rather, it seems to follow his personality that he would "allow" Pepper to finally marry him.